# Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed. Do not work with only WIndows 7 Starter (not with Home Edition)

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-7

The point is that debugging my C# app I faced the error: UriFormatException was unhandled. I've created p2p console chat.

And debugging stops at

> chatClient.Open()

with logs 
"Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed."

chatClient is an object of my class inherited by public interface IPeerChannelChat 
with

```
[ServiceContract(
    Namespace = "http://slickthought.net/peerchannel",
    CallbackContract = typeof(IPeerChannelChat))]
```

It should be mentioned that this code works in Windows 7 Home Edition.

But Windows 7 Starter shows me this exception.

Have you got the same experience?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Full code available here: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/308558/Invalid-URI-The-hostname-could-not-be-parsed

Answer (score 1):

Guessing: Could it be that chatClient.open spawns a new process, and since Windows 7 Starter edition is limited to only three concurrent processes it stops because of that?

Comment: Maybe. But it confused me that the wording is "Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed." So I guess this should me about Web. I assume the deal is that W7 Starter couldn't use IPv6 addresses. Do you think smth about that?